# lining 3 divs up side by side

Tags: css, html

could somebody please tell me how put  divs side by side within another div. I need one div to have a width of 50% and two divs next to this div to have widths of 25%, all with a height of 100%.

```
<div class="contents">
<h1>Hero Carousel...</h1>
                    <p>Sed pharetra, nulla ac blandit hendrerit, justo lacus tempus leo, non fermentum elit tellus at enim.</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your example code does not relate to what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
  <div style="float:left;background-color:red;width:25%;text-align:center;">25%</div>
  <div style="float:left;background-color:yellow;width:50%;text-align:center;">50%</div>
  <div style="float:left;background-color:green;width:25%;text-align:center;">25%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much, I know this is bad practice but could you also show me how to add 2 more divs under the 25% divs so I have 4 smaller square divs and still the one large 50% div? Thank you so so much

Comment: To put two 25% divs under each other, see and try [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fKTq6/), if you need to calculate the height of the middle div use some JS.